# How to extract subnet from full address from a Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, extract, subnet

I have created a temporary dataframe as below:

```
var someDF = Seq(("1","1.2.3.4"), ("2","5.26.6.3")).toDF("s/n", "ip")
```

Is there a way to extract the subnet out from the full ip address and put into a new column "subnet"?

Example of output:

```
---------------------------
|s/N | ip       | subnet  |
---------------------------
|1   | 1.2.3.4  | 1.2.3.x |
|2   | 5.26.6.3 | 5.26.6.x|
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `UDF` to do this:

```
val getSubnet = udf((ip: String) => ip.split("\\.").init.mkString(".") + ".x")

val df = someDF.withColumn("subnet", getSubnet($"ip"))
```

Which would give you this dataframe:

```
+---+--------+--------+
|s/n|      ip|  subnet|
+---+--------+--------+
|  1| 1.2.3.4| 1.2.3.x|
|  2|5.26.6.3|5.26.6.x|
+---+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your requirement with `concat_ws` and `substring_index` [*inbuilt functions*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
someDF.withColumn("subnet", concat_ws(".", substring_index($"ip", ".", 3), lit("x")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following: Very simple code but will improve your performance:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{ concat, lit, col }

someDF.withColumn("subnet", concat(regexp_replace(col("ip"), "(.*\\.)\\d+$", "$1"), lit("x"))).show()
```

`Output`

```
+---+--------+--------+
|s/n|      ip|  subnet|
+---+--------+--------+
|  1| 1.2.3.4| 1.2.3.x|
|  2|5.26.6.3|5.26.6.x|
+---+--------+--------+
```